# Acumatica: No limit assigned for inventory

Tags: acumatica

When I create sales order in Acumatica.The error I am receiving says One or more lines have unassigned Location and/or Lot/Serial Number.
I try to search in Inventory Summary and I see my inventory has Available -790 so Acumatica doesn't allow create order.How can I set unlimited for that.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear this is a programming question. General usage questions and technical support on Acumatica should be handled through the Acumatica product support.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the information for the location in SOLine (Transactions)

eg:

```
Soline.LocationID = 3;
```

and/or
 Lot/Serial Number information in SOLineSplit (splits)

eg:

```
    SOLineSplit newsplit = SOgraph.splits.Insert();
    SOgraph.splits.Current.LotSerialNbr = line.LotSerialNbr;
    SOgraph.splits.Current.Qty = line.Qty;
    SOgraph.splits.Current.UOM = line.UOM;
    SOgraph.splits.Update(newsplit);
```

If your item do not have lot/serial numbers, you can assign 'default shipping location' in warehouse and 'default receipt to' in the item information. So that it will use the defaults and allow you to continue.